# Image displayed according to product ID, If no image found then display default.

Tags: php, html, image

I have a product catalog - according to the product id it will pull from the images folder the image with the same product id. IE product 44, will pulll image 44.jpg.
My problem is, if no image is stored that matches the product id, I want it to display a default image.

I have tried:

```
<img id='currentPhoto' src='images/app_images/$applicationid.jpg' alt='App Icon' onerror='this.src='images/app_images/default.jpg''>
```

From this code, I get that the image cannot be found. When I looked at the image url, it was trying to find the product id  but couldnt from the image folder, which is correct, but if it cannot find the image, i want the default one to be shown instead.

Other code I have tried:

```
<object data='images/app_images/$applicationid.jpg' type=image/jpg'>
            <img src='images/app_images/default.jpg' alt='Product picture'/>   </a></object>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `<img id='currentPhoto' src='images/app_images/$applicationid.jpg' alt='App Icon' onerror="this.src='images/app_images/default.jpg'">` (it's all in the quotes)

Comment: Ok, this was because it was embeded in php. I have reorganised and put what you have put. By doing this, I am now just getting the default image shown, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong quotes which will make it not work. Use double quotes for your `onerror` attribute:

```
<img id='currentPhoto' src='images/app_images/$applicationid.jpg' alt='App Icon' onerror="this.src='images/app_images/default.jpg'">
```

Comment: Ok, this was because it was embeded in php. I have reorganised and put what you have put. By doing this, I am now just getting the default image shown, any thoughts?

Comment: That means your original `src` doesn't exist. Is the URL to your image correct?

Comment: yes. before I added the error control the correct image was displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img id='currentPhoto' src='images/app_images/$applicationid.jpg' alt='App Icon' onerror="this.src='images/app_images/default.jpg'">
```

The concatenation was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use .htaccess control stored in my images folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /images/app_images/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ default.jpg
```

This worked.